# Get the current UI language from a webpart

Tags: language, web-part

How can I get the selected language in the screenshot, from inside of a webpart?

[alt text http://thomasstock.net/currentlanguage.png](http://thomasstock.net/currentlanguage.png)

I'm using SharePoint 2010. My webpart is a "visual web part" created in VS2010.

I'm trying things like `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.RegionalSettings` and `SPContext.Current.Web.Language`" but ofcourse these things have nothing to do with that setting. :-|

Can someone please help me? What property am I looking for.

Comment: Please note. If user changed UI language via interface, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID keeps previous value. Use cookie "lcid" to get actual culture.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the **System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID** to get the current  LCID

Comment: also System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.LCID is the same.