# Get the current UI language with ECMAScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the display language from within ECMAScript?
Similar to [Get the current UI language from a webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/get-the-current-ui-language-from-a-webpart), I'd like to get the user's display language, however I want to access it with the Client Object Model in JavaScript (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538253.aspx). Is it somehow possible to access the *System.Threading* namespace? Or are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have two easy ways to get the LCID in SP JavaScript

1. var lcid =_spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage;
2. var lcid = SP.Res.lcid;

Note that option 1 returns an int (i.e. 1033) and option 2 return a string (i.e. "1053").

Comment: Great, thanks a lot Wictor! Both are working perfectly!

Comment: Great, Wictor! Is it possible to convert lcid to culture name in javascript? like 1033-> en-us, 1053 -> sv-se?

Comment: Another option is to directly use the 'L_Menu_LCID' variable in page. More here:
http://vrdmn.blogspot.in/2011/08/javascript-lmenubaseurl-varaible-for.html

Comment: _spPageContextInfo.currentUICultureName will give you en-US

Answer (score 5):

In my case I needed to know the language before the SharePoint javascript libraries are loaded in order to hide elements before they are shown on the screen (not possible with _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames).

Turns out SharePoint sets the lang attribute of the root HTML element according to the language and as a bonus it's already translated to the "en-us" format.

This is done with a simple call to 
`document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('lang')`

Answer (score 3):

Yet another ways to determine `LCID` in SP via JavaScript

1 Global variable `g_wsaLCID`:

```
var lcid = g_wsaLCID;
```

2 `Language` property of `Web` client object via CSOM (JavaScript)

```
function getWebLocale(complete) {

    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();

    context.load(web);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
                function(sender, args){
                    var lcid = web.get_language(); //returns LCID
                    return complete(lcid); 
                }, 
                function(sender, args){
                    complete(-1);
                });
}      

//Usage
function printWebLanguageSettings(){ 
    getWebLocale(function(lcid){
       console.log(lcid);
    });
}    
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(printWebLanguageSettings, 'sp.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the Bing translation, the methods above didn't work (the values don't get updated when the language is changed).

What worked for me was

```
LanguagePicker.currentLang
```