# Javascript/jQuery - check language and replace word problem

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, jquery, language

I need to replace one word in my SharePoint site, depend in on that what language is used. I found this question: [Get the current UI language with ECMAScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6915/get-the-current-ui-language-with-ecmascript)

I tried to use that code and it works only, if I add it into script editor and my page is in edit mode. If I try to add it to master page, it won't work. If I add it to external js-file, it won't work:

Firebug gives error message:

> "SP.Res is undefined"

Master page code: `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded("multilanguage.js", "sp.js")`

If I try to use other solution (same link, last post), Firebug gives error message:

> "ReferenceError: g_wsaLCID is not defined"
>
> "var lcid = g_wsaLCID;"

My example code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lcid = SP.Res.lcid;

if(lcid == "1033")
{
    alert('English'); /* Works only, if it in script editor and page is in edit mode */
}
</script>
```

What I'm doing wrong? How I can get it to work? Why it is working only script editor and page is edit mode?

Comment: SP 2010 or 2013?

Comment: SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the file name in `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`. but the function you want to trigger. Try this in your masterpage (2010)

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    var lcid = SP.Res.lcid;

    if(lcid == "1033")
    {
        alert('English'); /* Works only, if it in script editor and page is in edit mode */
    }
}, "sp.js")
```

Comment: Thank you! It works also SP 2013. What if I want to use external js-file?

Comment: If you want to use an external js file you need to make it SP.SOD compatible, more here: http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2010/08/sharepoint-scripts-on-demand-spsod.html