# Getting current site language

Tags: language

I want to get the current site language as I am implementing a custom module that will depend on web language. I am new to SharePoint and the company is using multi language site or site collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to retrieve site's language. 
Using javascript:

```
//Current Language
console.log(_spPageContextInfo.currentCultureName);
console.log(_spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage);
console.log(_spPageContextInfo.webLanguage);
console.log(SP.Res.lcid);

var currentLocale = "<%= SPContext.Current.Web.Language %>";
var globalLocale = "<%= SPContext.Current.Web.Language %>";
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('lang');
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what is the SP.Res

Comment: It's equivalent to .resx file but in client side. Open you fav console editor (Firebug, IE tools, chrome ) and type SP.Res. you'll see all the available properties and values

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

`SPContext.Current.RegionalSettings.LocaleId` - Gets the regional settings object of the current HTTP context in Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Also you could load language from current web

`SPContext.Current.Web.Language` - Gets the locale identifier (LCID) for the default language of the website.

Reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e12a6797-e6b2-44c8-840c-1c09623b7a84/how-to-get-the-language-of-current-sharepoint-portal?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

[SPWeb.Language property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.language.aspx)

To Use Java Script:

You have two easy ways to get the LCID in SP JavaScript

1. `var lcid =_spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage;`
2. `var lcid = SP.Res.lcid;`

[Get the current UI language with ECMAScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6915/get-the-current-ui-language-with-ecmascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript, there's an object available for you called: _spPageContextInfo, and then you can access currentLanguage, like:

```
_spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage
```

It will give you the language ID, in English it's 1033. You have to know ID for each language you want and that's it.